# Count number of strings starting with < = or >

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an application where I need to count the number of strings starting with a "<", "=", or ">". COUNTIF doesn't give the required result.

I can replace the initial characters with some other character, but is there a neater way round this?

[image]

The strings are formatted as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `=COUNTIF(A:A,"<abc")` the `<` has the special meaning lower than. But it has that special meaning only if it is the first character in the criteria expression.

So if you want to count only if the content is exactly "<abc"

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=<abc")
```

There the `=` is the first character with the special meaning equal.

The other counts would be:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"==abc")

=COUNTIF(A:A,"=>abc")
```

Wildcards are also possible:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"=<a*")
```

Comment: Perfect. I have realised it also applies to strings starting with <=, >= and <>. You could put =COUNTIF(A:A,"<><>abc") if you wanted to exclude all strings like "<>abc" !

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of items in column **A** starting with **<**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A:A,1)="<"))
```

**EDIT#1:**

and to speed up the formula use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A100,1)="<"))
```

Comment: Entire column references! More than one million rows to calculate, even if only ten are populated!

Comment: Do you know of a way to escape the literals?  I.e., use `>` and `<` with `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: No, I believe that you can use a backslash sometimes but it doesn't work here.

Comment: @XORLX  I have fixed the *Answer*